# PHP app with mysql and long running backup

Tags: php, mysql, performance, apache

I have PHP application using mysql as its database. The application is not heavy, normally it loads immediately. It has admin page, where I can run some queries which might return very long lists. There is also cron process backing whole database few times a day.

I noticed, that user pages which normally loads very fast can time-out or become slow when backup or long running (about 30sec) admin query is taking place.

Server is single processor virtual machine. I think that even if there's another thread using database, it should still respond 2 or 3 times slower, not like 100 times slower.

So how should I address this problem ? Can I set priority to mysql query or can it be more PHP-Apache problem ? I don't have too much information about it, because it happens rarely and mostly just reported by users.

I will be happy for any hint where to start looking because I don't want to test/debug production site nor install test environment. 
Thank anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the backup being taken?  mysqldump?

Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?  Sounds like MyISAM?

Regardless of the answers to my questions, here is what you are faced with:  The dump is hitting the disk vary hard, and it is probably blowing out the cache in RAM.  (The details depend heavily on the answers.)  This inherently slows things down.

Furthermore, if you are using MyISAM, then the *table* is locked; this is far worse than if InnoDB were being used.  InnoDB uses row locks and is less invasive, but not free.

What is the setting of key_buffer_size and/or innodb_buffer_pool_size versus how much RAM is *available*?  Those can have a impact whether the "cache is blown".

Comment: I'm using innodb. It might be the disk problem+proc, because I also bzip the backup. My ram is 1G, db backup is just 50MbBzipped, but the log files are gigs.

Comment: For only 1GB of RAM, I would set key_buffer_size to perhaps 10M and innodb_buffer_pool_size to perhaps 100M.  The buffer_pool is beneficial to your query.  How many CPU cores?  If only 1, then it is probably terribly busy with bzip.  Suggest backing off -- less CPU and less compression.

Comment: What log files are you backing up?  Most of them are a waste (for backing up).

Comment: We back up custom app.log (bussiness logic) error.log(small - usually) and also access.log. We run money related business, so we need to keep  the logs, sometimes we check the history half year back. Bzip is actually problem. Changing to gzip helps quite a lot. Can I run zip at low priority ?

Comment: In Unix you can "nice" the gzip process, but it may require building your own pipeline script.  If you have multiple CPU cores, it may not help any.

Comment: Assuming the logs are "write only", consider backing up only the latest piece of the business logs.  This may involve some kind of flushing at backup time.